# C++ removing elements in array by index/value

Tags: c++, arrays

I have problem with removing elements from array by value of elements.
I create a function which remove elements from array by index, now i want to use this function to remove element of array by value.

Here is my code:

```
bool Array::RemoveAt(int index)
{
   if (index < 0 || index >= number_of_elements)
       return false;

   for (int i = index; i < this->number_of_elements-1; i++)
   {
      this->arr[i] = this->arr[i + 1];
   }
      this->number_of_elements--;
      return true;
}

bool Array::RemoveByValue(int value)
{

   for (int i = 0; i < this->number_of_elements-1; i++)
   {
       if (this->arr[i] == value) {
          this->RemoveAt(i);
          return true;
       }
       else
          return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`RemoveByValue()` is ignoring the last element in the array. You need to get rid of `-1` in that loop.

Also, the `return false;` is causing the function to exit prematurely. It needs to be moved outside of the loop.

Try this:

```
bool Array::RemoveByValue(int value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this->number_of_elements; ++i)
    {
        if (this->arr[i] == value)
        {
            this->RemoveAt(i);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

On a side note, I would suggest tweaking the loop in `RemoveAt()` to the following:

```
bool Array::RemoveAt(int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= number_of_elements)
        return false;

    for (int i = index + 1; i < this->number_of_elements; ++i)
    {
        this->arr[i - 1] = this->arr[i];
    }

    this->number_of_elements--;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you use `this->number_of_elements--;` it doesn't actually make the array smaller, the array is still using x bytes of memory, you just change the integer.

The reason `RemoveByValue()` isn't working is because you're returning a false in the first loop iteration. So like, it sees the first element, is it equal to value? No, OK, end the function. You need to move that `return false;` out of the loop.